# I am building an robotic arm by using flex sensor, servo and 2 xbees

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, xbee

Rx Code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myServo;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
myServo.attach(9);
delay(5000);
myServo.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()==0);

    int d = Serial.read() - '0';
    if(d>0)
    {
      int pos = map(d,0,9,0,180);
      pos = constrain(pos,0,180);
      myServo.write(pos);
      Serial.println(d);

      delay(50);
      }
      else
      {};

}
```

Tx code:

```
int sensorValue = 0;         // the sensor value
int sensorMin = 1023;        // minimum sensor value
int sensorMax = 0;           // maximum sensor value
int SensorMid = 0;
const int POWER_OF_TWO_TO_AVERAGE = 6;

void setup() {
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  while (millis() < 10000) {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    sensorValue = analogRead(A1);
    if (sensorValue > sensorMax) {
      sensorMax = sensorValue;
    }
    if (sensorValue < sensorMin) {
      sensorMin = sensorValue;
    }
  }
  SensorMid = (sensorMin + sensorMax )/2;
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  }

void loop() {
int val = map(analogRead(A1),SensorMid,sensorMax,0,9);
Serial.println(val);
delay(100);
}
```

I am building a robotic arm and I am facing some problems regrading to the servos stability with the flex, I am using the flex as the transmitter and the servo as the receiver, and when I press my finger my servo doesn't move properly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show your code (a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problems), your wiring diagram or schematic, and a more detailed description of the "doesn't move properly" issue. Otherwise, all anyone can do is make uninformed guesses.

Comment: @josecanuc, Please refer to the question, since I have edited the question

Comment: what does this mean? `i press my finger`

Comment: I am using flex sensor, it gives the signals by bending your finger @jsotola

Comment: Have you tried taking a mean of for example 10 or 20 consecutive readings? All analog signals have noise on them, which you can reduce by taking the mean value

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the actual problem of "doesn't move properly", what I initially see is that you are transmitting values 0-9 by using `Serial.println()`, which sends the byte data, and also a newline (ASCII value `10`), so your RX code is probably getting alternating input of the intended value, and the value `10`, which is getting subtracted from `48` (the ASCII value of `'0'`), `map`ped and `constrain`ed to `0`.

Try changing your TX script to call `Serial.print()` instead. Your receiver doesn't care about each value showing up on a new line -- it doesn't know about lines.

Comment: What I mean by it doesn't move properly, that when I try bending the flex sensor, I guess that the servo doesn't receive the data properly due to the flex sensor resolution.

Comment: I think that the servo is not stable because that the flex is keep sending values even when I’m not touching it, how can I solve this problem @jose can u c

Comment: Why do you think that? If you want help from the public here, you have to provide actual data.